# Using OpenCV stitcher class to create a panorama from multiple images: Idea for calcualation time reduction

Tags: opencv, opencv-stitching

While using OpenCV stitcher class to stitch images to a panorama I have noticed that calculation time isn't increasing linearly with the number of images like I expected. It's increasing rather exponentially. I wonder why... I think its because the algorithm tries to stitch every image with every other one but I got a specified order of images so this is not needed and I hope I can reduce calculation time this way.

However I think I identified the part in the code which is responsible for the high calcualtion time (at least).

If I'm not completely mistaken it's from line 446-450:
https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/modules/stitching/src/stitcher.cpp?rev=7244

Maybe someone can explain this code part to me or even tell me how I can adapt the algorithm to stitch the images in a specified order instead of trying to stitch every image with every other image. I hope you understand what I mean because I really need help. I'm totally stuck right now ...